# invalid syntax error

Tags: python

My code is:

```
if any(s in attrs["show"] for s in ("Apple Mac OS","Intel Mac OS")):
```

the error is:

```
 if any(s in attrs["show"] for s in ("Apple Mac OS","Intel Mac OS")):
                            ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I could run the same script successfully on one machine, then I just copied it to another machine, it returns this error, really don't know why

Comment: Could you share a bit more code and your python version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an older version of Python on the machine that won't run it. Like, a really old version; this feature was added in Python 2.4, I believe.

Comment: Python 2.3 or earlier; python 2.4 gives a `NameError` for `any` instead.

Comment: 2.4 according to wikipedia ... The expression could be turned into a list-comp ... (that goes back to 2.0)  (reference:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python )